# Shapefile with ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, shapefile

I like to know if there is a Class, in objective-C, that manipulates shapefile (read/write/edit)?

I have found a bunch of stuff on kml files but nothing about shp files, but definitely want to avoid the need of converting  files format (shp->kml).

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning to acknowledge either of these answers?

Answer (score 11):

There's one from Pascal Brandt, ... (it's a little simplistic, but it certainly does the trick for me) ... [CocoaShapeFile](http://3dgeo.net/CocoaShapefile/CocoaShapefile.htm). He's just dressed up the C functions in Objective-C clothes, but it works just fine for reading. If you're shooting for iOS instead of Cocoa then you'll have to do just a little transcoding/conversion yourself.

With only a little bit of effort, I was able to get it running on the iPad, using MapKit, and using reference counting instead of garbage collection (not available on iOS).

To potentially ease your pain a little (granted, I don't know what you plan to do with shapefiles), but I've released a quick and dirty git repository, [iOS-Shapefile](https://github.com/grgcombs/iOS-Shapefile), that shows you how to get shapefile shapes (like points and polygons/polylines) into an iOS MKMapView.

As for writing and editing, (since that was beyond my interest), I think you'll likely have to roll your own methods, deviating from what I've provided here.

Answer (score 5):

See the [Shapelib Libarary](http://shapelib.maptools.org/)  It's written in C, but is usable in Objective-C, as OBJ-C is a superset of C :)

Comment: Technically you would not be able to use the Shapelib library because it has a LGPL license which is not compatible with the App Store.

Comment: Are you sure? I think you mean GPL, not LGPL. Do you have a source?

Comment: Seems Shapelib is actually under a dual license, supports MIT